# How to retrieve Caller and Callee class for signals(emit, connect) in python?

Tags: python, pyqt, runtime

My goal is to retrieve the caller and callee class names during program runtime for each signal emitted. The problem is explained using the file "scenario.py". So we can see that for every "emit" statement i can print out the Caller class during runtime by adding a print statement just above the "emit" statement. But the callee class on the other had was not possible since I dont have the information about the callee object and also what function it would callee. The connect statement does show the callee class but i need to retrieve information during runtime so in general it was not possible to retrieve the callee class?

```
#Scenario.py
class A (QObject):
        def __init__(self):
            QObject.__init__(self)

        def afunc (self):
            print self.__class__.__name__, "Printing"   <-- Caller class is retrieved
            self.emit(SIGNAL("Printing()"))
Class B:
       def bfunc(self):
            print "Hello World!"

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    a=A()
    b=B()
    QObject.connect(a,SIGNAL("Printing()"),b.bfunc)
    a.afunc()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Expected OutPut :
A  Printing()  B
```

So is it possible to retrieve In general the Caller class information during Run time ? The above scenario is a sample code. There could be situation where the emit statements is in different file and the connect statements are in different files of an application.

Answer (score 2):

`QObject`s have a method [`sender()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#sender) that allows you to get the sender of a signal from within the called slot, so it's easy to get the sender from within the called method (`bfunc`):

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys

class A (QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    def afunc (self):
        self.emit(SIGNAL("Printing()"))

class B(QObject):
    def bfunc(self):
        print self.sender().__class__.__name__ , "Printing()", self.__class__.__name__
        print "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    a=A()
    b=B()
    QObject.connect(a,SIGNAL("Printing()"),b.bfunc)
    a.afunc()    
    app.processEvents()
```

From within `afunc` you can't really know who's listening for the signal you're emitting, there could be no or multiple receivers.